# Change a string in a file with sed?

Tags: linux, sed, awk, gawk

I have a inputfile with template as shown below. I want to change the Version: using sed.

```
    Package: somename
    Priority: extra
    Section: checkinstall
    Maintainer: joe@example.com
    Architecture: i386
    Version: 3.1.0.2-1
    Depends:
    Provides: somename
    Description: some description
```

Currently I am getting the current version using `grep -m 1 Version inputfile | sed 's/[:_#a-zA-Z\s"]*//g'` and I am trying to replace the current version with `sed 's/3.1.0.2-1/3.1.0.2/' inputfile`

However this does not seem to work, but when I try it in command line using echo it works.
 `echo 'Version: 3.0.9.1' | sed 's/3.0.9.1/3.2.9.2/'`

```
Output: Version: 3.2.9.2
```

Any help on how I can accomplish this would be appreciated. Preferably I would like to change the version without getting the current version in the file.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need the grep.

```
sed -i '/Version/s/3\.1\.0\.2-1/3.1.0.2/' <files>
```

Answer (score 8):

You want to use the "-i" switch to sed for "edit file [I]n place."

See sed man page: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed

Answer (score 4):

The name `sed` literally comes from "Stream EDitor" - the behavior you're seeing is the way it was designed. When you say:

```
sed 'some commands' file
```

it reads the file, executes the commands and prints the result - it doesn't save it back to the file (although some versions of `sed` have some options to tell it to do that). You probably want to do this:

```
sed 'some commands' file > newfile
```

Then verify that `newfile` is correct, and then `mv newfile file`. If you're absolutely certain your edit script is correct, and you can deal with the consequences of overwriting your file with wrong data if they're not, then you might consider using the in-place editing flags, but it's generally safer to save to a temporary file so you can test/validate.

Comment: This is my way, is there a better way? I find -i not so trustful

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo, the last dot should be a dash, try this:

```
sed 's/3.1.0.2-1/3.1.0.2-2/'
```

Comment: Sorry the typo was my mistake in my bash script it is correct. Thanks for pointing it out though.