# Using sed in red hat linux to replace text

Tags: linux, sed

I have some XML files in a directory and they all include the tag: `<difficult>0</difficult>`. I just want to change that to `<difficult>1</difficult>`.

I'm using the following command:

```
sed 's/difficult>0/difficult>1/g' *.xml
```

All that happens is that the full XML text of all the files gets displayed, with the `difficult` tag showing a value of 1, but nothing happens to the actual files. When I open them, they still all contain `<difficult>0</difficult>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change a string in a file with sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919554/change-a-string-in-a-file-with-sed)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash, Remove empty XML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735715/bash-remove-empty-xml-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/difficult>0/difficult>1/g' *.xml
```

[Change a string in a file with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919554/change-a-string-in-a-file-with-sed)

Comment: You don't have the privileges for nominating duplicates yet, but in general, if you fInd a duplicate, please leave a comment with a link instead of answering. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `sed` usually puts its result on `stdout`. To change the files in-place, use the `-i` flag:

> ```
>   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
>           edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

One more time :)

Don't use regex to parse HTML. Using a proper parser & [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
xml ed -L -u '//difficult/text()' -v "1" file
```

`xml` is [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

Check: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)